# Show a message for few seconds and then reload the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On buttonSave click after saving the record successfully ,I want to show “Save successfully “ message on a label on a page for few seconds  and then reload the page.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: great!! So what do you need? Someone to test your code?

Comment: your accept ratio is too low but you can use page refresh meta tag or javascript of any kind

Answer (score 1):

You can add a META refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=SomeURL">
```

Comment: Shoban - Read my question carefully, before making any comments

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the 'meta' tag. This will reload the page after 3 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
```

To do this in code, you can do something like this in your submit event (C# syntax but it should be easy enough to understand):

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta()
{
    HttpEquiv = "refresh",
    Content = "3"
};

Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

For this to work, you need to have a `<head runat="server">` on the page.

Comment: How do I do this on a userControl? which is loaded on content page?

Comment: Not sure I follow, the code should work from within a user control too.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a nice overlay busy message.

**The Mark-up part:**

```
$(function() { // when document has loaded

    ($.unblockUI); //unlock UI

    //Show busy message on click event and disable UI
    $('#btnHelloWorld').click(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h4><img src="busy.gif" />Please wait...</h4>' });

    });

});

<asp:Button ID="btnHelloWorld" runat="server" Text="Hello World" /><br/>
```

**The Code behind:**

```
   Protected Sub btnHelloWorld_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnHelloWorld.Click
        Label1.Text = "Hello World"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Sub
```

Check out [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about ASP, yet I'll tell you a simple idea, you can use timers, and add a trigger to the timer as when the timer is out, the trigger is fired. Hope I have helped you ...